# Azure DevOps Query - show all work items I was involved yesterday

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I would like to query all work items from Azure DevOps I was involved yesterday.

Now I'm using following query:

[image]

So I get all work items I've changed yesterday, so that's ok, but the problem is that "Changed By" returns the last person which have modified the work item. Because of that if someone else did some action on the work item he overwrites the "Changed By" field and results of this query are not as I would expect.

I would like to display all work items that I was involved yesterday - I had changed the state, the assigned to person, made a comment etc. - I would like to query all these items.

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Adrian, can you try querying with History field. see if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Comment: I didn't find any solution unfortunately and right now only idea I have is to create custom extension for Azure DevOps and use WIQL or sth like this to achieve my goal..

Comment: @AdrianBystrek, Is there anything wrong with my answer? Does it not work for you? If yes, please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: You solution gives me all work items I ever changed while I want to get only work items that were changed by me at the specific date (yesterday).

Comment: @AdrianBystrek, Sorry, I posted the error image, I have updated it, would you please check if it help you now?

Comment: I think that the result is still the same :) You give me all items that were changed yesterday, but not necessarily by me. While I want work items that were changed yesterday, but only by me.

Answer (score 6):

> Azure DevOps Query - show all work items I was involved yesterday

To resolve this issue, you could use the Operator `Was Ever` instead of `=`:

[image]

This will return the work items which **was ever changed by someone**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Won't this find the same item repeatedly for every new change that happens going forward? So, I changed a work item last week, but someone else changed that work item again yesterday, now it's showing up again in this query.